# Regex for valid filename in WindowsXP

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a string of text that becomes part of the filename that gets saved out. I need to remove any illegal characters (ie non alpha numeric, only latin based characters)

This is what I have so far:

Figured it out, regex-fu levels back to normal!

```
function isValidFilename(fname)
{ 
  var rexp = new RegExp(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/gim)
  return fname.replace(rexp, "")
}

var v = "my$filename"
alert(v + "\nis valid???\n\n" + isValidFilename(v))

v = "myfilename"
alert(v + "\nis valid???\n\n" + isValidFilename(v))
```

Comment: Let me give you my regex-fu : [here](http://www.myregextester.com/index.php)

Comment: Valid for which OS? `lpt1` is an invalid filename on Windows, for example.

Comment: @TimPietzcker How come? Is that because it has no extension?

Comment: Why you're describing one task - "remove specific set of invalid symbols", but your solution is "remove everything but completely different set of another symbols"?

Comment: @inhan: No, it's a reserved name, like `NUL` and `COM2` and many others.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771/how-check-if-given-string-is-legal-allowed-file-name-under-windows

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thanks for the information. I had no idea (I'm on a mac so I'm not very familiar with the Windows filesystem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should validate against valid characters instead of removing invalid characters

^ inside a [] group will negate that group.

you can use replace with /[^A-Za-z0-9.-]/ to eliminate all characters that do not belong in this group

Answer (score 2):

found this in another question:

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z\^\&\'\@\{\}\[\]\,\$\=\!\-\#\(\)\.\%\+\~\_ ]+$/
```

taken from: [Javascript regex for validating filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100821/javascript-regex-for-validating-filenames)

Maybe you can use this one to get were you want?

Comment: I had a look at that link earlier but it hasn't helped my regex-fu :(

Comment: Yeah? And Отчёт.doc or Kaya - 火車.mp3 is suddenly invalid? No, really?

Comment: I've figured it out and adjusted the code. It's not bullet proof (it fails on Отчёт.doc as all letters get replaced; but it was only every designed for English text and that'll do for now.