# How to check filename string not to be a filepath

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, security, filesystems

I am writing a server application on node js. Operating system is Linux.

I receive filename as a plain string, so it can be hacked. Then I concatenate the filename string and path string like this:

```
filepath = '/home/www/upload/' + filename;
```

I want to protect an upload script from writing to anywhere except upload folder [or it's subfolders : optional], using my application logic, not Linux.

My current naive solution is blocking filenames which have `..` substring. I don't care if someone has filename with two dots.

Sure, when it comes to security, I have to ask the audience for advice: can anything go wrong?

Comment: I would follow some of the guidances from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100821/javascript-regex-for-validating-filenames Basically, avoid anything not being `[a-zA-Z0-9]` and just a few more characters.

Comment: @fedorqui I think if would be better to use node's filesystem or path API.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `path.resolve` for this:  http://nodejs.org/api/path.html

Try 
`filepath = path.resolve(filepath)`

and then

`goodPath = filepath.startsWith('/your/allowed/upload/dir');`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (path.basename(filepath) != filename) {
  // reject that sukka
}
```