# Validating file name for creating file in windows, using regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to read file name from a text box which is given by the user for creating file in windows. So I need to restrict the special characters to be entered in that text box `\ / : * ? " < > |`

How I can validate in javascript function using regular expression? I tried the below code.

```
var rg1 = new RegExp('/^[^\\/:\*\?"<>\|]+$/');
if (rg1.test($("qcAttachmentName").value)) {
    showErrorDetails("Enter a valid Attachment Name", 0);
    return "";
}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far. People will be more inclined to help you that way than if you expect a full solution without effort on your part.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript regex for validating filenames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100821/javascript-regex-for-validating-filenames)

Comment: @Amal Dev , That post is not helping me.

Comment: the accepted answer fixes your regex, but your regex is not correct for checking filenames under Windows, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script and regex pattern does have some errors.
Please find the [fiddle here](http://jsbin.com/pegezafoce/2/) for the working sample

Comment: Waw, This is working for me. But I need to allow blank space also, can you please give this.

Comment: It still doesn't allow blank space.

Comment: Doesn't allow blank space. This thing works - ^(?=[\\S])[^\\\\\\/:*?\"<>|]+$ 

I just removed all the blank spaces in the regex given in above fiddle code.